# java can't assign array inline to non-local variable

Tags: java

This compiles and works:

```
public class Test {
    public static int[] array;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] temp = {42};
        array = temp;
    }
}
```

This doesn't:

```
public class Test {
    public static int[] array;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        array = {42};
    }
}
```

Why is this? How can I assign arrays to non-local variables without using a temporary local variable?

Comment: Arrays can only be assigned in this way during declaration.

Comment: eclipse message: **Array constants can only be used in initializers** simple like that ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable has already been declared. You need to assign it thus:

```
array = new int[] {42};
```

Answer (score 0):

Initializers can occur only in the point of declaration.
In your case you have already declared the `array` as a `static` member so you missed your chance...